# Versionless gradle dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, ivy

When I do this

```
dependencies {
    file('libs/something.jar')
}
```

I have `something.jar` in my distribution.
But, when I to push the dependency to remote repository (ivy or maven) and want to use it from there, gradle always adds a version postfix to the jar.

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.company', name: 'something', version: '1.0'
}
```

results in `something-1.0.jar`.

Even this

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.company', name: 'something'
}
```

results in `something-.jar` (note the dash).

Can I somehow prevent the repository dependency to have a version?

(My motivation is that the jar is a 3rd party jar, I don't want to have it in git repo but I also don't want its name to change.)

Comment: It's a pretty fundamental concept of repositories that artifacts (jars) are uniquely identifiable by GAV (group/artifact/version). Imagine that a bugfix for the jar is released... how would we differentiate the old jar from the new jar? (spoiler alert: it's a version number!)

Comment: @lance-java It's a third-party enterprise-level library. I'm ok with versioning the library in the repository on our own, I just don't want the version number in the file name (and in classpath) after it has been resolved from the repository.

Comment: ok, I'll add an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, you're ok with giving the artifact a version in the repository. You just don't want a version in the jar in your application. You could do

```
configurations {
    something { transitive = false }
}
dependencies {
    something 'org.company:something:1.0'
    something 'org.company:something-else:1.0'
    compile files(tasks['dummyTask'])
    compile 'org.foo:some-normal-dep:1.1'
}
task copySomething(type:Copy) {
    from configurations.something
    into "$buildDir/something"
    rename '(.+)-.+?\\.jar', '$1.jar'
}
task dummyTask {
    dependsOn copySomething
    inputs.dir "$buildDir/something"
    outputs.files fileTree("$buildDir/something")
}
```

The main enabler for this is that [Project.files(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files(java.lang.Object...)) can accept a `Task`

Comment: This is almost it, the files are copied and renamed, but for some reason, the copy task output directory is treated as if it was a dependency now. ListJars outputs "something" instead of "something.jar".

Comment: Updated to use `Project.copy(...)` and customised task inputs/outputs

Comment: This seems to work for the hardcoded something.jar file. What if `configurations.something` contains multiple files and I want to do something like `rename '-1.0', ''`? I thought I could do something like `outputs.files configurations.something.getFiles() (and rename)`, but configurations.something.getFiles seems to be empty at that time.

Comment: If there's more than one file to rename, you can use a regex with a capturing group in `rename` eg: `rename '(.+)-.+?\.jar', '$1.jar'`

Comment: Yes, but the problematic part is this `outputs.file "$buildDir/something/something.jar"`

Comment: ah, then use `outputs.files fileTree("$buildDir/something")`. Or maybe`outputs.dir "$buildDir/something"`

Comment: Tried that already, it works, but not quite well. The files are gathered *before* the copy is performed, so at first it gives me zero dependencies, then it copies the files and only if I do another refresh, it takes the files previously copied into that directory. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: It's a hack but see my update. I've introduced a dummyTask

Comment: This still doesn't work in Idea (need to do refresh dependencies after build), but works when running `gradle build`, so I'm guess it's the best I can get. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: I'm not sure what task Idea invokes to get the dependency information from Gradle. If you find that out you could add a dependency from that task to `dummyTask`. Perhaps you could add a `doFirst {...}` to every task in your build to do a `println`